# How did names of foreign gods find their way into the Torah and Hebrew language?

Tags: hebrew, avodah-zarah, language

After having found one explanation that the origin of the Hebrew word ["Shachar" שחר](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahar_%28god%29) which is used in the context of "Alos HaShachar" is the name of a foreign god. As well that ["Shemesh" שמש](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamash) which we call the Sun is also a word that seems to be used to refer to a foreign god. How can we understand how these words found their way into the Torah and Hebrew language (whether it be that they literally mean "dawn" and the "sun" and are used to refer to the gods or that these are the actual names of the gods.) Or is it that they are indeed originally Hebrew words that mean "dawn" and "sun" (respectively) and were "borrowed" by another langauge/religion and used to refer to a particular god of theirs.

Comment: Seemingly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8977 and, sort of, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9036

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3461 and much more closely: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/why-use-babylonian-calendar-instead-of-our-own